# Can not import snappy in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, snappy

I use the package named python-snappy. This package requires [snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/) library. So, I download and install snappy successfully by the following commands such as:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

When I import snappy, I receive the errors:

```
from _snappy import CompressError, CompressedLengthError, \
ImportError: libsnappy.so.1 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Python 2.7, snappy, python-snappy and Ubuntu 12.04
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean "Python 2.7", not "Python 1.7"... ?

Comment: Thanks jonc, I have edited to Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally you might have to run the `ldconfig` utility to update your */etc/ld.so.cache* (or equivalent as appropriate to your OS).  Sometimes it might be necessary to add new entries (paths) to your */etc/ld.so.conf*.

Basically the shared object (so) loaders on many versions of Unix (and probably other Unix-like operating systems) use a cache to help resolve their base filenames into actual files to be loaded (usually *mmap()'d*).  This is roughly similar to the intermittent need to run *hash -r* or *rehash* in your shell after adding things to directories in your PATH.

Usually you can just run `ldconfig` with no arguments (possibly after adding your new library's path to your */etc/ld.so.conf* text file).  Good *Makefiles* will do this for you during `make install`.

Here's a little bit more info: http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/ldconfig/

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [python-snappy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-snappy) and [libsnappy1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libsnappy1) from the ubuntu repos:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsnappy1 python-snappy
```

You should not have to download anything.

Answer (score 1):

the following worked for me:

```
$ conda install python-snappy
```

then in my code I used:

```
import snappy
```

Answer (score 0):

Here for e.g. anaconda python

1. Download snappy from [github](http://google.github.io/snappy/)
2. also download the python file
3. extract both files
4. google-snappy folder

   `$ ./configure`

   `$ make`

   `$ sudo make install`
5. Then in python folder:

   `$ python setup.py build   # here I get the same import _snappy error`

   `$ python setup.py install # after this import works`